# WebView show image as text after uploading

Tags: android, android-intent, webview, onactivityresult

I have `WebView` with interface for uploading image. After uploading `WebView` have to show small uploaded image, but it shows a sequence of symbols.

expectation and reality

[image: Screenshot]

[image]

```
    web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.account_webview);
    web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    web.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(), "HTMLOUT");
    web.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    web.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    web.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(true);

    web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

            if (url.substring(url.length() - 3, url.length()).equals("pdf")) {
                Log.e("shouldOverrideUrlLoadi", "pdf ");
                web.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + url);
            } else if (url.equals(getResources().getString(R.string.urlHome)) || url.equals(getResources().getString(R.string.urlPaymentIndex))
                    || url.equals(getResources().getString(R.string.urlDetailIndex))) {
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.back_left_out, R.anim.back_right_in);
            } else{
                web.loadUrl(url);
            }

            return false;
        }

    });
    web.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {

            mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType("image/*");
            QueryActivity.this.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
        }

        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType) {
            mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType("*/*");
            QueryActivity.this.startActivityForResult(
                    Intent.createChooser(i, "File Browser"),
                    FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
        }

        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture) {
            mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType("image/*");
            QueryActivity.this.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"), QueryActivity.FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE );

        }

    });
```

and `onActivityResult`

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                Intent intent) {
    Log.e("Result"," "+requestCode+" "+resultCode);
    if(requestCode==FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE)
    {

        intent.putExtra("outputFormat", Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG.toString());
        if (null == mUploadMessage) return;
        Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != RESULT_OK ? null
                : intent.getData();
        Log.e("Result"," "+result);
        mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
        mUploadMessage = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you are loading in the URI of the image, not the image itself. A URI isn't an image, it is a uniform resource identifier that, as the name says, is used to identify a resource to be utilized in a uniform manner.

Comment: No. I check , the image is uploaded correctly, but does not display properly

Comment: Are you saying that 
                web.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + url); doesn't show an image, but the image is uploaded/embedded?

Comment: No, it's a part of web page. this does not fit

Answer (score 0):

i think you converted the image to String and then transfer image to server

```
intent.putExtra("outputFormat", Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG.toString());
```

so, check once that you are displaying the image or String format of image

Comment: It didn't help. The image correctly uploaded to server, but it shows it like symbols. On IOS version of app it works perfectly